# Node.js - io.sockets.in(room) not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
client.on('msg', function(msg){
    //io.sockets.in(msg.room).emit('msg', msg);
    client.get('room', function(err, room) {
          io.sockets.in(room).emit('msg',msg);
    })
});
```

is sending the message to ALL rooms and not just 'room' but I dont userstand why. I am using

```
client.set("room",name,function(){ return true; });
```

I am setting the value on('join'), I dont see how its even an option to send to all rooms when using in() surely if it finds nothing it defaults to not sending to any, not sending to ALL?

[My full server.js code](http://pastebin.com/1V0DHY20)

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
   socket.on("load Ex",function(data){
      io.sockets.in(parseInt(data.coneference)).emit('ex mesajlar', allData);
   });
});
```

At your client side, you have to trigger `load Ex` via button click or document Ready event then create a listener 
socket.on in client side.

```
socket.on("ex mesajlar",function(data) {
    alert(data.msg);
});
```